# How these files are continuously updated?

Tags: github, serverless, building-github-actions

I came across the repository: https://github.com/SauravKanchan/NewsAPI, where some of the data files(`everything/` and `top-headlines/category/`) are periodically updated and commited. Please explain if you can deduce how its being done,

Is it
a. some github action?
b. serverless lambda?

or something else.

Comment: https://github.com/SauravKanchan/NewsAPI/blob/master/main.py is the runner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably saw, the user updating is named "DataUpdaterBot". It looks like someone wrote a bot that checks for news from cnn, bbc etc (probably checks rss feed and then parse it to json)
Does it really matters where this bot is deployed?
As I interpret it, this bot starts every 30 minut

I checked github action for this repo- rather not (empty)

It looks like simple service that can be triggered by cron on any server